# How to create TensorFlow classification from the created model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow and I want to build a classification program with the model that has been created. Please take a look the tensorflow program here: https://github.com/wwoo/tf_box_classify. I managed to run the tf_convnet_test.py and it created the model.ckpt. How do I use this model to predict a new input (I am just throwing similar image as an input)?

Comment: Use test data, and calculate your prediction. Be sure you don't train it by running `sess.run(train_op)`

Comment: Do you have any exact example for that? Sorry i am quite new to tf.